# VBO's on Android: Pointing out the correct image in texture coordinate buffers

Tags: android, opengl-es

Does anyone know how to point out a given section of the texture buffer array stored in a HW buffer? I'm drawing a triangle strip and filling it with a square image. In my texture I have two square images next to each other, so the texture coordinate buffer points out them out with a total of 16 floats.

**With software buffers** I'm doing this to access the second image in the texture:

```
textureCoordinateBuffer.position(8);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureCoordinateBuffer);
```

**With hardware buffers** I assumed I do something like this:

```
// setup HW buffers
// ...
// select HW buffers
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexCoordinateBufferIndex);
gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordinateBufferIndex);

// Point out the first image in the texture coordinate buffer
gl11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
// Draw
// ...
```

Which works nicely if you want to point out the first image in the texture.
But I would like to access the second image - so I assumed I do this in the last line:

```
// Point out the second image in the texture coordinate buffer - doesn't work!
gl11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 8);
```

But this renders a scewed and discolored image.

Anyone who knows how to to this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the NeHe Android Tutorials.  They go into this in detail and show you what you need to do.

Specifically, the lesson you are looking for is here:
http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/

Lesson 6

You might not be binding and enabling the buffers, here's a snippet from the tutorial:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        //Bind our only previously generated texture in this case
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        //Point to our buffers
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        //Set the face rotation
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);

        //Enable the vertex and texture state
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

        //Draw the vertices as triangles, based on the Index Buffer information
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer);

        //Disable the client state before leaving
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }
```

Credit: Insanity Design - http://insanitydesign.com/

Edit:
I see what you're asking.  Here's more code that should be able to help you then.  If you look into the SpriteMethodTest app for android:
http://apps-for-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/SpriteMethodTest

You'll notice that Chris Pruett (The developer of this app) shows you the multitude of ways to draw textures to the screen.  Below is the code (I believe) you're looking for.

### Grid.java

```
public void beginDrawingStrips(GL10 gl, boolean useTexture) {
        beginDrawing(gl, useTexture);
        if (!mUseHardwareBuffers) {
            gl.glVertexPointer(3, mCoordinateType, 0, mVertexBuffer);

            if (useTexture) {
                gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, mCoordinateType, 0, mTexCoordBuffer);
            } 

        } else {
            GL11 gl11 = (GL11)gl;
            // draw using hardware buffers
            gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertBufferIndex);
            gl11.glVertexPointer(3, mCoordinateType, 0, 0);

            gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mTextureCoordBufferIndex);
            gl11.glTexCoordPointer(2, mCoordinateType, 0, 0);

            gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndexBufferIndex);
        }
    }

    // Assumes beginDrawingStrips() has been called before this.
    public void drawStrip(GL10 gl, boolean useTexture, int startIndex, int indexCount) {
        int count = indexCount;
        if (startIndex + indexCount >= mIndexCount) {
                count = mIndexCount - startIndex;
        }
        if (!mUseHardwareBuffers) {
            gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, count,
                    GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndexBuffer.position(startIndex));
        } else {
                GL11 gl11 = (GL11)gl;
            gl11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, count,
                    GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, startIndex * CHAR_SIZE);

        }
    }
```

Specifically, you'll want to look at the code where it takes the false branch of !mUseHardwareBuffers.  I suggest you look at the full Grid.java file for a better representation of how to do it because he also sets up the texture pointers and enables OpenGL to start drawing.

On a Side Note:  I suggest reading this from Chris also: 
http://www.scribd.com/doc/16917369/Writing-Real-Time-Games-for-Android

He goes into what this app does and what he found the most effective way of drawing textures was.

Comment: Hey, thanks I'll check out the tutorial. In your example you're using SW buffers but I was referring to HW buffers, I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @emolaus I added more to my answer, take a look.

Comment: Oh man I get it now, he binds the data between vertex and texture coordinate buffers with that index buffer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @emolaus np, glad I could help.